# Service in AngularJS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I working on simplest possible AngularJS app based approach to understand the flow of it. I trying to pass simple string from service to controller and from there I want to print this string in index.html. It seems my rest of code is working but not service and not sure what I am missing here...

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularFormsApp">
 <head>
 <title>Angular Form</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="App/AngularFormsApp.js"></script>
  <script src="App/EmployeeForm/efService.js"></script>
  <script src="App/EmployeeForm/efController.js"></script>

<!--<script src="App/EmployeeForm/efDirective.js"></script>
-->
</head>
  <body>
     <h1>Test AngularJS App Approach</h1>

   <div ng-controller="efController">
       {{employee}}
   </div>

</body >
</html>
```

### AngularFormsApp.JS (module)

```
var angularFormsModule = angular.module('angularFormsApp', []);
```

### efController.js (Controller)

```
angularFormsModule.controller('efController',
  function efController($scope, efService) {

    $scope.employee = efService.employee;
});
```

### efService.js (Service)

```
angularFormsModule.factory('efService',
 function () {
    var employee = "Employee Detail Available";

    return employee;
});
```

Comment: This is a well composed question. Hope you get it working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to return an object instead of a string.

```
angularFormsModule.factory('efService',
function efService() {
    var service = {
        employee: "Employee Detail Available"
    }
    return service;
});
```

Comment: Your not returning a function, simply an object.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `factory`, you need to return an object which contains the `properties` and `methods` to be accessed from outside with this factory instance.

```
angularFormsModule.factory('efService',
 return {
     employee : "Employee Detail Available"
});
```

Comment: `this` is for services I think.

Comment: Ya I'm confused by `service` in `efService` while he actually used a `factory` method

Answer (score 1):

you are actually calling a local service var which is not exposed by your service, in your controller:

```
 $scope.employee = efService.employee;
```

you are returning a function with your factory, so you should use it as such in your controller:

```
 $scope.employee = efService();
```